# Including a php on file request

Tags: php, include, server-side-includes

I would honestly be surprised if anything like this exists, but I couldn't find anything relevant with my Google-fu.

I'm including a PHP file using `require_once()` on every page of my site. The file is a light custom-made framework.

I was wondering if I could drop the entire `require_once()` line and, by using another obscure mechanism, include the library at the beginning of every file in a specified folder.

The reason behind this is that the files in that particular folder are going to be modified by people with limited coding knowledge and I don't want them screwing up the PHP lines thinking they're not important.

**EDIT:** The library will be ultimately distributed and aims to work on typical PHP installatons.

Thanks!

Comment: Just say the file is autogenerated and that all changes are erased eventually :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another technique that I feel is less obscure than `auto_prepend_file` would be to have all requests to this folder first redirected to one file, that then loads the library, and then loads the file you're going to have these other users modifying.

Here's how I've parsed this sort of thing using your rewrite code...
If the htaccess file is in the same directory as the folder, I think the rewrite rule will look like this: 
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

In the index.php file I usually load some sort of configuration for the site, followed by delegating.
I use this function right here to get the current url... I'm not entirely sure if it's overkill or not, but it's worked consistently for me across several platforms.

```
function get_current_url() {
 $pageUrl = 'http';
 if (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageUrl .= "s";}
 $pageUrl .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageUrl .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageUrl .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }

 return $pageUrl;
}
```

Then you can essentially parse the result of get_current_url() using php's `parse_url()` function and delegating appropriately.

Comment: This can be good, but my htaccess skills are rusty. I must be sure that I don't lose any query strings, and allow any file structure. Here is what I got so far: `RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /framework/index.php/$1 [L]`. It intercepts the file request just fine, but I could use a hand getting `$1` and using it...

Comment: @RémiBreton I've expanded my answer a little bit ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is very possible, using a `php.ini` directive [`auto_prepend_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file).

So, for instance, in the appropriate .htaccess file:

```
php_flag auto_prepend_file header.php
```

Comment: This is very interesting, as it is mostly transparent. But let say this "framework" would be widely distributed, can I assume that this technique would be valid to typical PHP installations?

Comment: I think doing things in an obscure and "magic" way is probably not a good way to go if you're going to distribute the framework. The single point of access style Anther recommends is the most popular.

Comment: Right, my bad, I should have been more precise in the question. Thanks for your quick answers though!